# label not clickable in jqtouch

Tags: iphone, jquery, ios, jqtouch

With following code I can not click on labels in jqtouch (on iphone simulator and iphone itself):

```
<ul class="rounded">
  <li>
    <label for="user_name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It is working well in safari, I have checked this also in demo of jquery-mobile and it is working on iphone simulator, so problem seams to be strictly jqtouch specific.

Comment: @gov it is an jquery library for creating websites for iphone: http://jqtouch.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks to @Ivan I found better solution:

```
  $('label[for],input[type="radio"]').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Additionally it fixes radio buttons.

The only downside is - it stops propagation, but in my case it is ok.

Answer (score 12):

There is an obscure trick for this, using CSS:

label { cursor: pointer; }

And it will work on iPhone and iPad.

Comment: This deserves a sincere WTF!

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in all cases. I went to try this out only to find that property was already defined. :(

Answer (score 2):

add onclick="" to the label

```
<label for="blah" onclick="">blah</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Tapping on <label> does not auto-focus linked  in Mobile Safari](http://dropshado.ws/post/1415930344/tapping-on-does-not-auto-focus-linked-in-mobile)

Comment: I already have similar fix, but it's hard to believe that 'Mobile Safari' does not support this obvious functionality:
    $('label[for]').bind('click', function() {
      var $target = $('#'+$(this).attr('for'));
      $(':focus').blur();
      if ($target[0].type==='radio') {
        $target[0].checked = true;
      } else {
        $target[0].focus();
      }
    });

Comment: I finally found in the related article a better solution, but as it was not straight only up vote.

Answer (score -1):

yeah, the user693942 CSS trick is enough, actually, it works!

```
label { cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: this looks like a bug, changing cursor should not change propagation of events - maybe it looks shorter/nicer - but it does not seems to be the proper solution (using bug to solve bug).