# Tapping on <label> in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, forms

Tapping on `<label>` does not auto-focus linked  in Mobile Safari but If an empty function as clickhandler is defined
like this

```
document.getElementById("test_label").onclick = function () {};
```

solves the problem.

This is the full source code.

```
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test" name="test">
    <label for="test" id="test_label">This is the label</label>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("test_label").onclick = function () {};
    </script>
</body>
```

Do you know why it works?

Comment: Can you post your html?

Is it

`<label for="someId">Tap here</label><input id="someId" ... />`

Comment: Thanks for question. Was looking for a workaround that bug. This onclick saved me :) If you filed a bug in https://bugreport.apple.com/ , let us know what they answered you.

Comment: [set the label element's cursor attribute to pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5560077) #wtf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you found a bug in iOS Safari. Congratulations! Finding and reporting bugs is addictive.

You can report this and other bugs to Apple at https://bugreport.apple.com/. Apple might not follow up immediately, but at some point in the future they should notify you that it was a duplicate of an existing bug, that they don’t consider it a bug, or (if you’re lucky) that you should test it again in a new version of iOS.

In the mean time, hold onto this workaround — you’ll need it.

Comment: Yay! I love Safari :)

Comment: Really? You must not be a web developer ;)

Answer (score 42):

People using FastClick:

Use this CSS:

```
label > * {
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

see this issue: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/issues/60

and this codepen: http://codepen.io/visnup/pen/XJNvEq

Comment: Didn't think of this, third party developed this hybrid app. did use fastclick

Answer (score 24):

We were able to work around this issue at Etsy by simply adding this single line of code to our global javascript file.

```
$('label').click(function() {});
```

We are using the xui micro js library and that line simply attaches an empty click handler to all `label` elements. For some reason, this magically fixes the issue on mobile safari.

Comment: On iOS 7 I'm still experiencing similar issues. Can't get `click` to fire on `label` tags. Bizarre and very very frustrating.

Comment: I had a similar issue with Bootstrap labels. I added this code with the class selector .label and everything worked.

Answer (score 6):

```
<label for="myID" onclick="">
  <input type="checkbox" id="myID" name="myNAME">
  <span class="name-checkbox"> My name for my checkbox </span>
  <span class="some-info">extra informations below</span>
</label>
```

To enable the tap on iOS everywhere on the label tag, you need to add to its direct children (expect input), pointer-events: none;

```
.name-checkbox, .some-info {
      pointer-events: none;
    }
```

Comment: I've been looking for this all day. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

i know it's not really nice markup: I just hardcoded an empty onclick like this `onclick=""` on each label. That worked on a wrapping label:

```
<label for="myID" onclick="">
 <input type="checkbox" id="myID" name="myNAME">
 Check to check
</label>
```

Comment: On wrapping labels it works anyway, the handler is not necessary.

Comment: On iPhone Safari, this didn't work right away. I had to set onclick=";"

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 7, this issue still persists without any of the workarounds working for me.

My solution was to combine the `click` event with `touchend`:

```
var handler = function(e) { /* do stuff */ };
$("ol input[type=checkbox] ~ label")
  .on('touchend', handler)
  .on('click', handler);
```

Some helpful info in this JQuery issue: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5677 Especially the part where it says technically there is no `click` event on mobile.

Answer (score 2):

adding onclick attribute would fix the problem.

```
<label for="test" id="test_label" onclick="">
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can let for="", and focus input when click the label, here is the code work in react

```
<input ref={(node) => { this.input = node; }} />

<label htmlFor="" onClick={() => { this.input.focus();}}/>
```

Comment: I had this issue today in an **Angular 7** project on **Safari iOS 12** with a custom styled checkbox. No visual state change occurred when clicking the label. Added template identifier attribute e.g. `#someid` to the input and `(click)="someid.focus()"` on the label ... and voila! Thanks :-D

Answer (score 0):

If there is already an onclick attribute, one should not override it and in my test, it worked (the onclick attribute) and clicked the checkbox too. so my solution is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("LABEL");
    var labels_l = labels.length;
    for(var l = 0; l < labels_l; l++){
        if(labels[l].hasAttribute("for") && (!labels[l].hasAttribute("onclick"))){
            labels[l].onclick = function () {};
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my similar problem like this:

```
input {
position: absolute;
width: 120px; // size of my image
height: 100px; // size of my image
opacity: 0;
display: inherit; // Because i'm hidding it on other resolutions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some really odd behavior has been happening for me where none of the above would fix it. If I had place text or images inside the label element, clicking on that element did not work. However when i added margin and a padding to the label, clicking on the margin or padding but not on the text/images did work. So what I did was make the label a 100% w 100% h absolutely positioned over my text & images.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <label class="label-overlay" for="file"></label>
  <img src="something.png">
  <p>Upload File</p>
  <input type="file" name="file">
</div>


<style>
  .wrapper{display:inline-block;}
  .label{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;cursor:pointer;}
</style>
```