# Checkbox toggle button not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to make an on/off toggle button using a checkbox input type and using CSS to change the style to have it look like the ones the iPhone uses for my webapp. Currently my button works great in all browsers however when I load it up on my iPhone it doesn't work, when you click the button nothing happens. At first I thought it might be a problem with my jQTouch or javascript but I removed all my CSS so I could just test the functionality and it worked fine. So I know the problem is somewhere in my CSS. Any idea why this CSS code doesn't allow me to click the button. (The graphics and everything work and look fine, just nothing happens when I click the button). Any ideas? Thanks.

Code is in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4gjZX/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. change to onclick
2. add an empty onclick to the label - [known issue on iDevices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142520/label-not-clickable-in-jqtouch)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/jMTRa/)

However why have inline event handlers when you use jQuery anyway???

Also why the data- in the ID, it is normally used for attribute names

Answer (score 0):

You may get it works by making some css changes:-

```
label { cursor: pointer; }
```